# сравнение строк "2" > "15" = true

Tags: javascript, javascript-faq

Прочитал мануал по поводу строк:
[Посимвольное сравнение](https://learn.javascript.ru/string#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Но не до конца понял суть сравнения:

```
"2" > "15"// Выдает true
```

Почему выдает true?

Если сравнивать по символам, то

```
"2" > "1"// true
```

Почему так?

Comment: Плохо читали. Символ `2` больше символа `1`, потому `("2" > "15") === true`. А насчет второго сравнения вы врете: `("2" == "1") === false`

Comment: все верно, 2 не равно 1, опечатался, там знак больше >

Comment: И что же вам теперь не понято?

Comment: не вижу где "2" больше "1"

Comment: Берутся коды символов, в данном случае: символу "1" соответствует код 49, а символу "2" - 50, 50 > 49, поэтому "2" > "1"

Comment: Не стоит минусовать вопрос. В его нынешнем виде он вполне легитимен.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, не учел что в input'ах стоит type="text")

Comment: @unsxxn, без разницы какой тип стоит у инпута. свойство `value` у него всегда строка.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Непосредственно сравнение срок происходит посимвольно - первый с первым, второй со вторым:

> Если первая буква первой строки больше – значит первая строка больше,
>   независимо от остальных символов:

Оператор нестрогого равенства `==` сравнивает по типу переменных. А оператор строгого равенства `===` сравнивает численный код символа. Т.к. `2` идёт после `1` (имеет больший код к кодировке Unicode), то двойка больше.

Больше информации по ссылке: [Сравнение строк](https://learn.javascript.ru/comparison#%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Answer (score 4):

[Немного спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison), выдержка алгоритма по сравнению строк:

для случая `x<y`

Если оба операнда строки, тогда:
Если `y` - префикс `x` - вернуть *false*. (строка *p* является префиксом строки *q*, если *q* можно получить добавив к строке *p* другую строку *r*. Обратите внимание, что любая строка является префиксом для самой себя, так как *r* может быть пустой строкой.)
Если `x` - префикс `y` - вернуть *true*.

Пусть *k* наименьший не отрицательный индекс для которого код символа из строки *x* отличается от кода символа из строки *y* (такое *k* существует в случае, если никакая из сравниваемых строк не является префиксом другой.)

Пусть *m* - это код символа *x[k]*
Пусть *n* - это код символа *y[k]*
Если *m < n*, вернуть *true*. Иначе, вернуть *false*.

**Обратите внимание:** сравнение строк использует просто лексикографический порядок последовательностей кодов символов. Здесь нет попытки использовать более сложное, семантически ориентированных определений равенства строк или символов и схем упорядочения, определенные в спецификации Unicode. Поэтому строки, которые являются канонически эквивалентными согласно стандарту Unicode, могут быть неравными. Фактически этот алгоритм предполагает, что строки уже находятся в нормализованной форме. Кроме того, обратите внимание, что для строк, содержащих дополнительные символы, лексикографическое упорядочение значений кодов символов UTF-16 отличается от того же, для значений *code point*.

Применительно к коду в вопросе:

"2" > "15"

Строки не являются префиксами друг друга.

*k* == 0,

*m* = "2"[0] == '2' = 50
*n* = "15"[0] == '1' = 49

50 > 49 -> результат сравнения *true*.